# R: how to add arguments to a function (in particular `...`)?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I think the following bit of code provides motivation for the question:

```
add <- function(x, y = 1) x + y
subtract <- function(x, z = 1) x - z
both <- function(x, ...) list(add(x, ...), subtract(x, ...))

both(1) 
# OK
both(1, z = 2)
# Error in add(x, ...) : unused argument (z = 2)

# a solution from a previous question I asked
add <- function(x, y = 1, ...) x + y
subtract <- function(x, z = 1, ...) x - z
both(1, z = 2)
```

So I'm looking for a function operator called `add_dots` say, which takes a function `f`, and returns `f` but with `...` added to its list of arguments

Cheers for any help

Comment: since you want to give the same argument to more than one function, no need to name it here.  `both(x=1,2)` works fine here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
add <- function(x, y = 1) x + y
#> add
#function(x, y = 1) x + y
formals(add) <- c(formals(add), alist(... = ))
#> add
#function (x, y = 1, ...) 
#x + y
```

After @agstudy 's comment, a function for it:

```
add_dots <- function(FUN)
{
 f <- match.fun(FUN)
 formals(f) <- c(formals(f), alist(... = ))
 return(f)
}

add <- function(x, y = 1) x + y
#> add
#function(x, y = 1) x + y
add_dots(add)
#function (x, y = 1, ...) 
#x + y
new.add <- add_dots(add)
#> new.add
#function (x, y = 1, ...) 
#x + y
```

Comment: Note that this works so long as the function `add` has no naming conflicts in its argument list (including the `...` user options), and that there are no conflicts in required argument names between `add` and `subtract` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: You're right! I just focused on the "add `...` arguments" part. Feel free to edit if you find something lacking.

Comment: @alexis_laz +1!your answer is what the OP is looking for ( add_dots function: maybe you should encapsulate it in a function) , but The OP don't explain how this can resolve his naming conflicts!

Comment: thanks - this is what I was looking for. I'm sure the fundamental concept could now be extended is necessary to make the function more robust e.g. check if `match.fun(FUN)` is primitive (in which case the formals would be `NULL`) or already has a dots argument. Cheers!